# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly Python 3

Tags: python, string

Im trying to do a small program but it wont work, I want to write 4 different numbers intenger and decimals, but it doesnt work. I get the error message TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. Can you guys help me?

```
a = str(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
b = str(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
c = str(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
d = str(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))

l = (a+b+c+d)
for l in range (a, d+1):
    print(l)
```

I want the program to print the numbers I entered under each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int has what you're looking for i think.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `d` as an integer:

```
for l in range (a, d+1):
```

by adding `1` to it, but you made it a string:

```
d = str(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
```

Make *all* your inputs integers instead:

```
a = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
b = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
c = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
d = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
```

Next, your `for` loop clobbers the `l` variable:

```
l = (a+b+c+d)
for l in range (a, d+1):
```

It isn't clear what you want to do in the loop, but the sum of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` is now lost as `l` is used as a loop variable too.

If you wanted to have decimals, you can use `float()` instead of `int()`, but note that `range()` can *only* work with integers!

If you wanted to print the 4 numbers in a loop, then create a list first and loop directly over the list:

```
a = float(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
b = float(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
c = float(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
d = float(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))

lst = [a, b, c, d]
for number in lst:
    print(number)
```

or combine looping with asking for the number and printing it:

```
lst = []
for count in range(4):
    number = float(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))    
    print(number)
    lst.append(number)
```

This asks for a number four times, prints the given number, and then adds that number to a list for later use.

Comment: I want the program to print the numbers I said under each others.

Comment: @user2916710: So you want `l` to be a list instead.

Comment: @user2916710: Please do also update your question (you can edit it) to add that information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
a = int(input("Ange ett siffervrde: "))
b = int(input("Ange ett siffervrde: "))
c = int(input("Ange ett siffervrde: "))
d = int(input("Ange ett siffervrde: "))
```

Comment: If I use int I can't use decimals,

Comment: @user2916710: Then use `float`, but note that `range()` does not take floating point values.

Comment: @user2916710: you need to tell us a lot more about what your program should **do** with the numbers here.

Comment: I want it to work when I use decimals too like this,                              a = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
b = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
c = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))
d = int(input("Ange ett siffervärde: "))

l = (a+b+c+d)
for l in range (a, d+1):
    print(l*1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Your variables a, b, c and d are strings, not numbers, so you cannot pass them as arguments to `range` nor add them to ints.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input("a=: "))
b = int(input("b=: "))

lst = [a, b]
for number in lst:
    print(number)
```

It's ok in my machine(python 2.6);